# Laravel Default App Hosted in Heroku Not Opening: '/' 404 Not Found:

Tags: laravel, heroku, php-5.6

I have tried hosting my laravel app in heroku. I have deployed successfully but when i access the url of the app it gives me error **"The requested resource / was not found on this server."**

I even tried hosting default laravel app but still it gives me the same error.

Below is the log file--

```
`G:\Web Projects\Laravel Infused\test_hero>heroku logs --tail
2015-11-13T11:03:39.491060+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by chppal50@gmail.com
2015-11-13T11:03:39.491060+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by chppal50@gmail.com
2015-11-13T11:05:32.793824+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by chppal50@gmail.com
2015-11-13T11:05:32.989689+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-11-13T11:05:32.989697+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-11-13T11:05:32.856334+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 137fa01 by chppal50@gmail.com
2015-11-13T11:05:32.856334+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by chppal50@gmail.com
2015-11-13T11:05:38.065345+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `php -S 0.0.0.0:21198`
2015-11-13T11:05:39.644080+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:05:39 2015] 10.150.135.101:23077 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
2015-11-13T11:05:39.650126+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:05:39 2015] 172.19.91.185:25380 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
2015-11-13T11:05:39.669496+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-11-13T11:06:20.050713+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:06:20 2015] 172.19.91.185:26740 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
2015-11-13T11:07:46.339610+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=something-in.herokuapp.com request_id=0ba70396-eb29-41c7-ac35-f5c34f8f6124 fwd="101.56.15.99" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=673
2015-11-13T11:07:46.334075+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:07:46 2015] 10.102.161.24:46905 [404]: / - No such file or directory
2015-11-13T11:07:46.833308+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=something-in.herokuapp.com request_id=4cd4ff7c-4fcc-4bb8-983f-4e6f101df61c fwd="101.56.15.99" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=684
2015-11-13T11:07:46.827859+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:07:46 2015] 10.102.161.24:24640 [404]: /favicon.ico - No such file or directory
2015-11-13T11:07:47.485815+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=something-in.herokuapp.com request_id=734aedcb-69af-4b54-8afd-e83d0a5b92fd fwd="101.56.15.99" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=684
2015-11-13T11:07:47.479083+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:07:47 2015] 10.102.161.24:58167 [404]: /favicon.ico - No such file or directory
2015-11-13T11:08:29.169026+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:08:29 2015] 172.19.91.185:30822 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
2015-11-13T11:10:38.062572+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:10:38 2015] 172.19.91.185:34904 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
2015-11-13T11:12:47.087438+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:12:47 2015] 172.19.91.185:39073 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
2015-11-13T11:14:56.283361+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:14:56 2015] 172.19.91.185:43653 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
2015-11-13T11:16:10.608140+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 7c04c33 by chppal50@gmail.com
2015-11-13T11:16:10.608140+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by chppal50@gmail.com
2015-11-13T11:16:10.745570+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-11-13T11:16:10.745580+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-11-13T11:16:10.884928+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-11-13T11:16:14.464544+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-11-13T11:16:16.123645+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-11-13T11:16:18.258165+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `php -S 0.0.0.0:8622`
2015-11-13T11:16:19.977393+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-11-13T11:16:19.958729+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:16:19 2015] 10.13.193.184:35681 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
2015-11-13T11:16:19.967154+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:16:19 2015] 172.18.47.13:51114 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
2015-11-13T11:16:20.394457+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:16:20 2015] 172.18.47.13:51182 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
2015-11-13T11:16:45.737385+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=something-in.herokuapp.com request_id=6749f618-ffaf-4cf6-909d-3863c0c97c76 fwd="101.56.15.99" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=673
2015-11-13T11:16:45.734626+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:16:45 2015] 10.113.143.241:33813 [404]: / - No such file or directory
2015-11-13T11:18:23.890482+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:18:23 2015] 172.18.47.13:53865 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
2015-11-13T11:20:28.112854+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:20:28 2015] 172.18.47.13:56541 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
2015-11-13T11:21:39.213155+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=something-in.herokuapp.com request_id=d6d88aca-323a-498f-a078-91934f45440b fwd="101.56.15.99" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=0ms status=404 bytes=673
2015-11-13T11:21:39.212410+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:21:39 2015] 10.45.79.55:37289 [404]: / - No such file or directory
2015-11-13T11:21:41.494168+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=something-in.herokuapp.com request_id=7faa7276-5951-4de4-9464-7adb9bf6987d fwd="101.56.15.99" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=673
2015-11-13T11:21:41.493255+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:21:41 2015] 10.45.79.55:48515 [404]: / - No such file or directory
2015-11-13T11:22:32.423762+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:22:32 2015] 172.18.47.13:59630 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
2015-11-13T11:24:36.043323+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:24:36 2015] 172.18.47.13:11373 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
2015-11-13T11:26:40.806829+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:26:40 2015] 172.18.47.13:15536 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
2015-11-13T11:28:44.307411+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:28:44 2015] 172.18.47.13:19018 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
2015-11-13T11:30:48.332884+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:30:48 2015] 172.18.47.13:23348 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
2015-11-13T11:32:52.088993+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:32:52 2015] 172.18.47.13:26026 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
2015-11-13T11:34:56.357200+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:34:56 2015] 172.18.47.13:28951 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
2015-11-13T11:37:00.104402+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Nov 13 11:37:00 2015] 172.18.47.13:31849 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)`
```

Comment: Have you deploy it or turn or `Enable automatic deploys` ?

Comment: I have already deployed the app and enable automatic deploy is also there...

Comment: Can you put some echo in the index.php file in your app and test ?

Comment: actually i believ the index.php is not loading at all.. iT gives me this Not found error

Comment: I guess that your app might be on sleep time, If you are a free user, then it will allow you to run only for certain hours/day. Can you check how much time you run the app in dashboard ?

Comment: Dude i just created the app.. Its not sleeping now

Comment: When I add public after my app domain name it works.. I.e iapac-dashboard.herokuapp.com/public works, but when i remove the public from the url it doesnt work it gives me access forbidden. But as soon as i add /public or public/ in my Procfile it gives me a '/' not found error.

Comment: See, then its a simple routing problem :)

Comment: Have you fixed it or shall i help you to fix it ?

Comment: Have fixed it.. Its not even a routing problem.. It was because i had enclosed the Procfile value with quotes `"web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/"` . After removing the quotes it is working flawlessly now.

Comment: yeah feeling great now

Comment: You shall post it as answer so that it would be helpful for future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have fixed it.. Its not even a routing problem.. It was because i had enclosed the Procfile value with quotes "web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/" . After removing the quotes it is working flawlessly now.